# netty 4.0.15 threads blocked

Tags: multithreading, netty, blocking, blocked-threads

can any one help me to understand the below thread blocks in netty4.0.15

```
nioEventLoopGroup-5-13 [BLOCKED] CPU time: 38s
sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(long)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select()
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run()
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run()
java.lang.Thread.run()


nioEventLoopGroup-5-2 [BLOCKED] CPU time: 40s
java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class)
io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.isSharable()
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.checkMultiplicity(ChannelHandlerContext)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast0(String, DefaultChannelHandlerContext)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(EventExecutorGroup, String, ChannelHandler)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(String, ChannelHandler)
org.zestadz.adsearch.server.impl.KomliAdServerInitializer.initChannel(SocketChannel)
org.zestadz.adsearch.server.impl.KomliAdServerInitializer.initChannel(Channel)
io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRegistered()
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRegistered()
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRegistered()
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(ChannelPromise)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$100(AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe, ChannelPromise)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run()
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(long)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run()
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run()
java.lang.Thread.run()
```

blocked threads i took it from yourkit profiler

Comment: Some thread is blocked on select().  Is there some problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal for a worker to block on select() waiting for incoming messages